# Authentication in Lumen 5.2

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, lumen, lumen-5.2

In the AuthServiceProvider;

```
Auth::viaRequest('api', function ($request) {
    if ($request->input('api_token')) {
        return User::where('api_token', $request->input('api_token'))->first();
    }
});
```

I can't seem to get this to work. `GET` requests do not have a `body` so no `input` is present.
Also I've tried using `$request->header('api_token')` but still getting `unauthorised`

If I do an independent search on the `DB` like below it works;

```
Auth::viaRequest('api', function ($request) {
        return User::where('api_token', 'my_api_key')->first();
});
```

Can anyone confirm that the `$request` header can be accessed here?

Comment: What does the request look?

Comment: Input for `GET` requests comes from the query string: `http://example.com/users?api_token=my_api_key`.

Comment: Still doesn't work. I've tried it with `POST` as well and it works with `POST` because I put the `api_token` in the body. Also you should know that you don't have `?` in `laravel/lumen` so I just modified my route to `/{api_token}`

Comment: lumen knows how to handle variables passed in via the query string just fine. If you pass in the `api_token` as part of your query string, you can access it just fine with the `$request` variable. However, it looks like you got the header method working, so that is good, as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before you read my answer, please read [this article](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/new_features_2_4.html) (just in case you're using Apache Web Server).

> Headers containing invalid characters (including underscores) are now silently dropped.

Ok, now to get your `api_token` value, you need to change your request header-field name to `Api-Token` (this is standard, you may read [this](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2616.txt)).

Now you can access your `Api-Token` value via:

```
$request->header('Api-Token', 'any-default-value');
```

If you really want to get your **non standard** header definition, you may use [`getallheaders`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.getallheaders.php) function. For more information, you may read `Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\ServerBag@getHeaders` method.